# Undetected-chromedriver не запускается

Tags: python, web-scraping

undetected-chromedriver, не работает, точнее не запускает браузер

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://someurl')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, помогла конструкция

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import undetected_chromedriver

    driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://someurl")
    time.sleep(5) # чтобы браузер не закрылся моментально
```

Попробуй такой код.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).